# Spivak Ch1, Q10: Express without absolute value signs: $|a + b| - |b|$

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am working through Spivak's Calculus on my own to improve my math skill.

I have come across the following question:

Express without absolute value signs: $|a + b| - |b|$.

I consider four cases:

**Case 1**

$a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$

Clearly in this case $|a + b| - |b| = a + b - b = a$.

**Case 2**

$a\geq 0$ and $b\leq 0$

In this case we have $|a + b| - |b| = a + (-b) - (-b) = a$.

**Case 3**

$a\leq 0$ and $b\geq 0$

In this case, $|a + b| - |b| = (-a) + b - b = -a$.

**Case 4**

$a\leq 0$ and $b\leq 0$

Here, $|a + b| - |b| = (-a) + (-b) - (-b) = -a$.

However, my solutions miss some of the solutions given in the book which I give below.

Can someone please help me out? What is missing in my case analysis. I am not sure how Spivak has jumped to considering the cases he has. Any guidance with thought process would be very helpful for me developing my skills.

[image: Book solutions]

Comment: your mistake is in cases 2 and 3. For example, in case 2, why does $a\geq 0$ and $b\leq 0$ imply $|a+b|=a+(-b)=a-b$? (trace through these steps for example with $a=10,b=-1$ to see the error). The definition of absolute value is $|x|=x$ if $x\geq 0$ and $-x$ if $x\leq 0$. So $|a+b|=a+b$ if $a+b\geq 0$ (i.e $a\geq -b$) and $|a+b|=-(a+b)$ if $a+b\leq 0$ (i.e if $a\leq -b$). So you always look at the cases when the thing inside is positive/negative.

Comment: Ah thank you, it looks like I misunderstood the absolute function! I will reread the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I was misunderstanding the absolute sign. With peek-a-boo's help I now have the following:

Either:

$a + b \geq 0$ in which case $|a + b| = a + b$.

or

$a + b \leq 0$ in which case $|a + b| = -a - b$.

So we have 2 cases for the left hand term.

Now we can do the same with the right hand term:

Either:

$b \geq 0$, in which case $|b| = b$

or

$b \leq 0$, in which case $|b| = -b$

Combining the 2 cases for the left hand term and the 2 cases for the right hand term gives us 4 outcomes:

$a + 2b, a, -a, -a-2b$ as the four possible values this expression can take.